# Is there any way to include automaticly excluded files into app.asar?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, asar

Electron builder exclude my `html-node-pdf` and `pdf-to-printer` libraries. I think it is because of their size but when my app is running in release mode the puppeteer package gives an error like:

`Failed to launch the browser process! spawn D:\RONESANS\RonesansKantar\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\html-pdf-node\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-901912\chrome-win\chrome.exe ENOENT`

**Because my html-pdf-node package is not in app.asar.**

Is there anyway to include these automatically excluded `node_modules` packages into `app.asar`?

Or a limit for `app.asar` unpacked maybe I can increase it?

I searched an option to include these unpacked `node_modules` but I cant find it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question after reading [ask] – namely, include the relevant sections of your package.json file, thanks. However, doing what you try to do will not work even if your packages are correctly included in the ASAR, because you cannot spawn processes from within the archive (unless specifically using `child_process.execFile`).